# "Every day if you want us to". What is the meaning of "to"?

Tags: ellipsis

"Every day if you want us to". What is the meaning of "to"? Why it can not be just "Every day if you want us". I do not understand sense of adding the word "to".

Comment: Welcome! You might get better-targeted answers if you edit to give the rest of the sentence you're imagining.

Answer (score 1):

There are three obvious ways of responding to a question such as:

What days can you come to visit your father at the hospice?

1. **We can come every day if he wants us to come (to visit him)**.
   The response is spelled out, with or without the bit in brackets.
2. **We can come every day if he wants us to (visit him)**.
   Here the response is shortened because both parties understand
   the answer
   to mean **to visit him**.
3. **We can come every day if he wants us (to visit him)**.
   This response is further shortened. Again the elided bit (in
   brackets) is understood. There's no need to spell it out.

So, it can be any of the three. Most people in conversation would not bother to spell out in full what will be understood in a shortened form.

If, for example, a child should ask a parent:
**Can I go to the cinema?**
A typical answer might be:
**If you want to.**
It's quite unnecessary to say
**If you want to go (to the cinema)**